# How to create hyperlink in Messagebox.show in ZK in Java?

Tags: java, messagebox, zk

In my ZK project with Java, I need to show a message box in which there needs to be a hyperlink, from which user can open another web page.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Supporting_Classes/Messagebox), the customization of the MessageBox is rather limited. There is a possibilty to completely change the UI via `MessageBox.setTemplate()`, but this affects all MessageBoxes.

---

In our project, we replaced zk's default MessageBox with our own, which works more like a dialog. With this, we are in full control over the content of the dialog.

```
public abstract class OurDialog
{
    private Window               window;

    private DialogListener       closeListener;

    public OurDialog(String title)
    {
        window = new Window();
        window.setTitle(title);
        window.setHflex("min");
        window.setSizable(false);
        window.setPosition("center");
        window.setContentStyle("overflow: auto");
        window.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLOSE, new EventListener<Event>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(Event event)
                throws Exception
            {
                if (closeListener != null)
                {
                    if ("confirmed".equals(event.getData()))
                    {
                        closeListener.onClose(OurDialog.this);

                        if (!closeListener.onCloseConfirmation(OurDialog.this))
                        {
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        closeListener.onCancel(OurDialog.this);

                        if (!closeListener.onCancelConfirmation(OurDialog.this))
                        {
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public final void setWidth(int width)
    {
        if (width != 0)
        {
            window.setMinwidth(width);
            window.setWidth(width + "px");
        }
        else
        {
            window.setHflex("min");
        }
    }

    public final void setHeight(int height)
    {
        if (height != 0)
        {
            window.setMinheight(height);
            window.setHeight(height + "px");
        }
        else
        {
            window.setVflex("min");
        }
    }

    public final void close()
    {
        Events.sendEvent(Events.ON_CLOSE, window, "confirmed");
    }

    public final void cancel()
    {
        Events.sendEvent(Events.ON_CLOSE, window, "cancelled");
    }

    /**
     * @param closeListener called when the dialog is closed.
     */
    public final void show(DialogListener closeListener)
    {
        setCloseListener(closeListener);

        window.appendChild(getContent());

        GUIHelper.setFocusToFirstInput(window);

        OurMeatApplication.getCurrent().showDialog(this);
    }

    /**
     * @return the component to be displayed in the dialog.
     */
    protected abstract Component getContent();
}
```

Our main application class (OurApplication) has a reference to the page and provides the method to show the dialog:

```
final void showDialog(final OurDialog dialog)
{
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setParent(page);
    window.doModal();
}
```

This is a very generic dialog implementation for pretty much any purpose. For the specific MessageBox case, we have a sub class that provides a prepared UI, error level indicators, several buttons to pick, and a specialised listener to listen to those buttons.